# React Typescript Fluent Ui -DetailList in onRenderItemColumn

Tags: react-typescript, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

i
I don't succeed to fix the bug
I need that in tablle show buttom

I copy the code from fluent UI https://developer.microsoft.com/de-de/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist/customitemcolumns
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAesZ.png)

but this in give bug in onrenderItem because the declared columns
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTj6E.png)
i try this but have bug
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMVmj.png)

Comment: this code with bug https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-cache-vgl3p?file=/src/DetailList.tsx

Answer (score 0):

i sucsses to fix the bug

```
return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <div className="ms-Grid">
                <div className="ms-Grid-row">
                    <DetailsList
                        items={item}
                        columns={columns}
                        setKey='set'
                        onRenderItemColumn={renderItemColumn}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);



const renderItemColumn = (item: any, index: any, column: any) => {
let fieldContent = item[column.fieldName];
switch (column.key) {
    case 'custem':
        return  <Link href="https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/link" >ukbkkbio</Link></span>

    default:
        return <span >{fieldContent}</span>;
}
```

}

https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-cache-vgl3p?file=/src/App.tsx